# How do add a class to the Wishlist Link in the Top Menu?

Tags: magento-1.7, wishlist, class, toplinks, topmenu

I want to add a class to the wishlist link in the top menu.

In my `app/design/frontend/default/abcd/layout/wishlist.xml`, I have a reference:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link" />
    <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

I know you can add a class using the `addLink` method as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16681785/3966682). However the `addLinkBlock` method [only takes one `blockName` argument](http://doc-magento.com/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php.source.html#l109). So how can I add a class to the wishlist link in the top menu?

Answer (score 3):

I followed some suggestions from this [Magento Forum post](http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/add-css-class-to-wishlist-link-top--59632.html), but none of them did the trick for me, but the last one was close. Here's what I did:

1. Copy `/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Links.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Links.php`
2. Inside the `_toHtml()` method, add `$this->a_params = 'class="your-class"';` just before the `return parent::_toHtml();` statement

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite the block `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Links` and add this as a member variable:

```
protected $_liPparams = 'class="some-class"';
```

or if you need the class on the `<a>` element add this:

```
protected $_aPparams = 'class="some-class"';
```